# Reducing clojure collections with state carried through

Tags: clojure

I'm learning clojure (coming from ruby) and having some trouble wrapping my head around the best way to generate collections.

I'd like to write a function that takes two arguments -- the vector `ary` and integer `sum` -- and generates a new 2D vector in which each row's sum is <= the input sum (ignore input validation). The conceptual point I'm having trouble with is how to keep the state of "sum of current row" while also building up a new collection.

Here's what I've got:

```
(defn split-after-sum [ary sum]
  (reduce (fn [acc i]
            (let [inner-sum (+ (last acc) i)]
              (if (< inner-sum sum)
                [(conj (first acc) i) (+ i (last acc))]
                [(conj (first acc) i "X") 0])))
          [[] 0] ary))
```

I'm passing `reduce` a 2 element vector in order to keep track of both the collection I'm building and the total count of this row.

It sort of works. I haven't figured out how to actually make the result a 2D array so it's just sticking "X"s where the splits should be:

```
(first (split-after-sum [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 2)) => [1 1 "X" 1 1 "X" 1 1 "X" 1 1 "X" 1]
```

Ideal output would be:

```
(split-after-sum [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] 2) => [[1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1]]
```

I know there are a few things jumbled up in here, but I think an idiomatic answer to this problem would be enlightening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(defn split-after-sum [ary sum]
  (let [[acc v] (reduce (fn [[acc v s] x]
                          (let [new-s (+ s x)]
                            (if (<= new-s sum)
                              [acc (conj v x) new-s]
                              [(conj acc v) [x] x])))
                        [[] [] 0]
                        ary)]
    (conj acc v)))

(split-after-sum [1 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 1] 3)
;= [[1 1] [3] [2 1] [1 1 1] [1]]
(split-after-sum [1 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 1] 4)
;= [[1 1] [3] [2 1 1] [1 1 1]]
(split-after-sum [1 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 1] 5)
;= [[1 1 3] [2 1 1 1] [1 1]]
(split-after-sum [1 1 3 2 1 1 1 1 1] 6)
;= [[1 1 3] [2 1 1 1 1] [1]]
```

Comment: This seems fairly similar to my approach - use reduce, keep state via multiple arguments to reduce. Do you consider this "good" clojure?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine Clojure. It's also really fast: in particular, it's faster than the `loop` / `recur` approach. `reduce` is a core concept in Clojure and its performance characteristics have received -- and continue to receive -- a great deal of attention. (I use [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) for benchmarking. Here I've benchmarked both approaches on the small vector used in the examples in the answer above, as well as two vectors produced by `(shuffle (range len))`, one of length 1024, the other -- 16384; the values of sum were 7, 17 and 173, respectively.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for benchmarking it. I'm less worried about speed and more worried about learning the right way to tackle problems, but it's a great sign to me that what I did intuitively is actually pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

As Michał shows, the cumulative state a can be joined in a tuple with the associated element.

Below is an imperative approach where the state is held in a loop binding.

```
(defn split-after-sum [ary sum]
  (when (seq ary)
    (loop [ary ary
           cur 0
           row []
           rows []]
      (if-let [[x & xs] ary]
        (let [nxt (+ x cur)]
          (if (<= nxt sum)
            (recur xs nxt (conj row x) rows)
            (recur xs x [x] (conj rows row))))
        (conj rows row)))))
```

Aside: the argument order should probably be reversed.  Functions that work over elements of sequences tend to take the sequence as the last argument.

Comment: Would you recommend this approach over the functional one?

Comment: I wouldn't call this imperative -- rather, it's looping by recursion, which is functional, if not quite as declarative as using a standard combinator (loop locals are rebound in parallel for the next iteration). See my response to spike's comment on my answer for some benchmarking results. I agree completely about argument order.